# How to get four following text inputs after each checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am traversing checkboxes like this:

```
$('.day').each(function() {
// here I need to get the following 4 text inputs in the HTML 
    // and set some attributes on them      
});
```

After every checkbox there are four text input fields (there are also some div, span tags for CSS around them). So inside the loop above I need to get four text input fields that follow the checkbox in the HTML source so I can set some attributes on them.

How would I go about that?

Comment: look on http://api.jquery.com/next/ or http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: How about the HTML source code? Would help a lot. [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) or [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) might be ok for you depending on your structure.

Comment: @Haim Evgi: `next` will only return the next sibling that matches, not several.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without the markup, but you could try this.

```
$('.day').each(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('input').slice(0,4).attr('someAttribute','somevalue');    
});
```

If there's some stopping point, like another `.day` element, you could use `nextUntil` then `.filter()`.

```
$('.day').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.day').filter('input').attr('someAttribute','somevalue');    
});
```

---

**EDIT:** When you say there are some `<div>` and other tags ***around*** them, I assumed that you meant ***in between*** them.

If you're actually saying that the inputs ***are nested in them***, then you could do something like this:

```
$('.day').each(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(':has(input)').slice(0,4).find('input').attr('someAttribute','somevalue');    
});
```

or perhaps this:

```
$('.day').each(function() {
    $(this).nextAll().find('input').slice(0,4).attr('someAttribute','somevalue');    
});
```

or again, if there's a stopping point you can indicate like another `.day`, use `nextUntil()`:

```
$('.day').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.day').find('input').attr('someAttribute','somevalue');    
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used the second one. Indeed there are stopping points. Between all .day checkboxes there are four text fields (from hours, from minutes, to hours, to minutes).

Answer (score 1):

if they are siblings within a parent container, you might be able to use `$(this).nextAll('input').each(function(){});` or `$(this).nextAll().find('input').each(function(){});` depending on your html structure.  Or `var p = $(this).parent(); if (p && p[0]) p[0].find('input').each(function(){});`

Comment: this does not treat the first 4 input field, but all input fields of element with class 'day'

Answer (score 1):

This is a total guess, since you've shown no markup whatsoever:

```
$('.day').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $inputs = $this.nextAll('input[type=text]');
    $inputs.each(function () {
        // do whatever with the inputs here
    });
});
```

Comment: this does not treat the first 4 input field, but all input fields of element with class 'day'

Answer (score 1):

if your trying to set css properties to the inputs you can use css selectors which are quite powerful, like this

```
.day ~ input {
  //set your styles for the input
}
```

what this means is you are selecting all the inputs exactely after .day

hope this helps.

Comment: what if he does not want the 5th input field be styled?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.day').each(function() {
     // get input fields
     var first_input = $(this).nextAll().filter('input:first');
     var second_input = first_input.nextAll().filter('input:first');
     var third_input = second_input.nextAll().filter('input:first');
     var fourth_input = third_input.nextAll().filter('input:first');

     // set attribute xyz to value
     first_input.attr('xyz', 'value');
     second_input.attr('xyz', 'value');
     third_input.attr('xyz', 'value');
     fourth_input.attr('xyz', 'value');
});
```

Comment: Will break if the structure is `<input ..><br /><input ..>...`.

Comment: @Felix is right. The question is pretty clear that the inputs are not adjacent. Remember that `.next()` *only* evaluates the immediate sibling. If the selector doesn't match that sibling, an empty object is returned.

Comment: Almost. ;o) I think you mean `.filter('input:first')` if you're targeting siblings.